# How to define the template for custom posts?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, advanced-custom-fields

I created a new custom type called 'books' and I created a Field using the Advanced Custom Fields plugin where I define the fields and create the records, with post names such as book1, book2, etc.
I want to define a view for the elements of this particular custom type so when the visitor goes to website.com/books/book1 I will display information about book1. I tried defining single-books.php at the root of the theme but it didn't work.
How can I define a template for the posts of a custom post?

Thanks

Comment: `single-books.php` would be correct for a CPT named `books`. However you may want to double-check your code and adjust so the name is `book` singular. When you say you added the file and it "didn't work," what happened? Did you confirm that a different template was being used?

Comment: Also, can you clarify your setup - are you actually creating individual "Book" posts in WP? From the way you worded your scenario it sounds like you might be trying to create just custom fields without associating them to a post. You'll need to create each actual "Book" post and you can then use ACF to add metadata for that post, and creating those posts is what actually allows you to go to `example.com/books/book1` - it relies on having an actual post with the slug "book1".

Comment: @WebElaine When I tried to access /books/name of post I got page not found. Any idea why?

Comment: @WebElaine regarding the second comment. Yes I created all the posts and their respective metadata using ACF.

Comment: After you registered your post type, did you visit the Settings > Permalinks page? This flushes permalinks and makes new permalinks work - you don't have to change any settings, but you do need to visit that page or use code to flush the rewrite rules.

Answer (score 1):

You can Use single-{posttype}.php for the single template.

And, if you have register your post type with the has_archive argument set to true, then you can use archive-{posttype}.php for your archive template.

You can check [Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/)

Also for 404 Page, double check that **page slug** and **post-type slug** is **NOT SAME**. I mean check whether you have created any page with slug **"books"**.